my error-state styling isn't being used and i can't figure out why
I'm working on a web based calculator using Python and Flask. I have a HTML, CSS, and JS file for the styling, and I ran into an issue. I have an info-box that has a start-state and error-state.
start-state: This is the default state that the info box should be in. The default text is 'Enter value(s) below and select an operation.' If I make a calculation such as 1 + 1 = 2, that whole thing will print out in the info box (1 + 1 = 2). If I hit the clear button, it will change the info-box back to its default state where it prints 'Enter value(s) below and select an operation.'
error-state: This is the state if the user enters an invalid answer (1 + two instead of 1 + 2 etc) and it would print out the text "Invalid Input" and also change the color of the info-box to red.
I tried to google and ask around, but I still can't figure out why my error-state isn't properly changing the background color to red.
Here is my code so far:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
      <style>
        .info-box {
            background-color: #FFECD7;
            color: #000000;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 0 auto 20px;
            max-width: 520px;
        }
        .start-state {
        background-color: #FFECD7;
        color: #000000;
        }
        .error-state {
         background-color: #B70F0A;
         color: #FFFFFF;
            }
        .container {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .calculator-form {
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: left;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .section-text {
         background-color: #EBEBEB;
         color: #000000;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .clear-button {
            width: 250px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: #EBEBEB;
            color: #000000;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
        label {
            font-size: 15px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 50px;
        }
        .operation-lists {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .operation-list {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            margin-right: 20px;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: left;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .error-message {
            color: red;
        }
        .operator-button {
            width: 250px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: #EBEBEB;
            color: #000000;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <div id="info-box" class="info-box start-state">
        Enter value(s) below and select an operation.
    </div>
    <div class="calculator-form">
        <form id="calculator-form" action="/calculate" method="POST">
            <label for="num1">Input A:</label>
            <input type="text" name="num1" id="num1" placeholder="0" required>
            <label for="num2">Input B:</label>
            <input type="text" name="num2" id="num2" placeholder="0">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="operation-lists">
        <ul class="operation-list">
            <h2 class="section-text">A and B</h2>
            <li><button class="operator-button" onclick="calculate('+')">A + B</button></li>
            <li><button class="operator-button" onclick="calculate('-')">A - B</button></li>
            <li><button class="operator-button" onclick="calculate('*')">A * B</button></li>
            <li><button class="operator-button" onclick="calculate('/')">A / B</button></li>
            <li><button class="operator-button" onclick="calculate('equals')">A == B</button></li>
            <li><button class="operator-button" onclick="calculate('power')">A ^ B</button></li>
            <li><button class="operator-button" onclick="calculate('log')">A log B</button></li>
            <li><button class="operator-button" onclick="calculate('root')">A root B</button></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="operation-list">
            <h2 class="section-text">A only</h2>
            <li><button class="operator-button" onclick="calculate('factorial')">A!</button></li>
            <li><button class="operator-button" onclick="calculate('sin')">Sin A</button></li>
            <li><button class="operator-button" onclick="calculate('cos')">Cos A</button></li>
            <li><button class="operator-button" onclick="calculate('tan')">Tan A</button></li>
            <li><button class="operator-button" onclick="calculate('reciprocal')">1 / A</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="calculator-form">
        <button class="clear-button" onclick="clearInputs()">Clear</button>

    </div>

    <div id="result"></div>
    <div id="error" class="error-message"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function calculate(operation) {
      var form = document.getElementById("calculator-form");
      var formData = new FormData(form);
       formData.append('operation', operation);

    fetch('/calculate', {
     method: 'POST',
     body: formData
})
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
   var resultText = formData.get('num1') + ' ' + operation + ' ' + formData.get('num2') + ' = ' + data;
      document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Result: ' + resultText;
      document.getElementById('error').innerText = '';
      document.getElementById('info-box').innerText = resultText;
      document.getElementById('info-box').className = 'info-box start-state';
})
    .catch(error => {
      document.getElementById('result').innerText = '';
      document.getElementById('error').innerText = 'Error: ' + error;
      document.getElementById('info-box').innerText = 'Invalid input';
      document.getElementById('info-box').className = 'info-box error-state';
});
}

function clearInputs() {
    document.getElementById('num1').value = '';
    document.getElementById('num2').value = '';
    document.getElementById('result').innerText = '';
    document.getElementById('error').innerText = '';
    document.getElementById('info-box').innerText = 'Enter value(s) below and select an operation.';
    document.getElementById('info-box').classList.remove('error-state');
}
</script>

This is my project, any help is appreciated!
I have tried to add the background colors within the Javascript code and it didn't change anything at all. My error-state function isn't being used and I tried to think of ways to include it into the code, but I am stuck.

Have you verified that the element class is being updated correctly? Have you used the DOM inspector to determine how the element style is being calculated?

There's nothing here which would cause the .catch() to trigger short of a low-level networking error. See the linked duplicate for details on handling unsuccessful HTTP response status
